# PDF Box Creates ZeroByte PDF

Tags: java, pdf, text, unicode, pdfbox

I am trying to convert a  unicode Text File to PDF using PDF box.

Task:
My method takes a  unicode encoded TextFile as input and output a PDF file.

Problem: 
The PDFs that are created have zero bytes. It is not writing  anything.

I am using 
Apache PDFBox  2.0.6

This is my code:

```
public class TexttoPDF {

    public File texttoPDF(File textFile) throws Exception {

        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        PDPage blankPage = new PDPage();
        PDFont font = PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN;
        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, blankPage);




        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(textFile), "UTF8"));


        String str;
        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.setFont( font, 12 );
        contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount( 100, 700 );


        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            contentStream.drawString(str);


        }


        contentStream.endText();

        document.save( pdffile.getName());
        contentStream.close();
        document.close();
        in.close();



    return pdffile;

    }
}
```

How this can be fixed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close your content stream before saving, not after saving. So change

```
    document.save( pdffile.getName());
    contentStream.close();
```

to

```
    contentStream.close();
    document.save( pdffile.getName());
```

(This is [described in the FAQ](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#emptypage))

Also add the page to your document after calling `new PDPage()`:

```
document.addPage(blankPage);
```

Comment: It solved the problem. However only one  line is written to the PDF.

Comment: Yes, that is a different problem. You need to call `contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(0,-24);` between calls. Be aware that you'll have to handle page changes yourself. See TextToPDF.java in the source download.